# How can I solve a rounding error using update_all in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rounding-error

Assume there is a table named `somethings` with a column `value` of type `float`.

The schema is shown below.

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: somethings
#
# id         :bigint   not null, primary key
# value      :float    not null
# created_at :datetime not null
# updated_at :datetime not null
```

Then, "update the value of all records in the somethings table to 0.4, then subtract 0.1".

The code is shown below.

```rb
Something.update_all("value = 0.4")
Something.update_all("value = value - 0.1")
```

After this operation, the value columns of the records in the somethings table are all `0.3000000000000000000000004`, resulting in a rounding error.

I want to update without rounding errors, but how can I do it?

Note that I am aware that if I write the following without `update_all`, there will be no rounding error.

```rb
Something.update_all("value = 0.4")

Something.find_each do |s|
  s.update(value: (s.value.rationalize - 0.1.rationalize).to_f)
end
```

However, I would like to use `update_all` as much as possible for faster updates, as performance is severely degraded when the `somethings` table has a large number of records.

Comment: The real question here is why you're using a float type column instead of a decimal which can properly handle normal arithmetical operations.

Comment: Thanks!
I was not aware of the data type.
Using decimal instead of float type solved it!

Comment: I feel like this website could not be more apropos https://0.30000000000000004.com/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: You can try using raw sql in update_all like this update_all("value = CAST(value AS DECIMAL(10, 9)) - 0.1").